# Does either the Xbox One or PS4 have an IR Sensor for Universal Remotes?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

Do either the XBox One or the PS4 have an IR Sensor so that they can receive commands from a universal remote control? The 360 did, but PS3 did not without a third party dongle.

I'd love to be able to control these devices from my Harmony remote in addition to just yelling at it...

Comment: Thanks for the tag fix cloudymusic; I didn't have enough rep here to create the xbox-one tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [this article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-33199_7-57611849-221/confirmed-ps4-wont-work-with-ir-remote-controls/) (emphasis mine),

> A Sony representative confirmed to CNET that **the PS4 cannot receive infrared (IR) remote control commands, which means it won't work with a traditional universal remote such as the Logitech Harmony 650**. We were also unable to find an IR receptor on our PS4 review unit, and **Sony says the PS4 Eye camera can't receive IR commands either**.
>
> For all those keeping score at home, **the Xbox One is capable of receiving IR commands**...

So:

- PS4 does not, nor does the PS4 Eye.
- Xbox One does.

This does not mean that there will not be middleware created to add this feature to the PS4 as was done to solve this issue for the PS3. It also doesn't rule out future iterations of the hardware from adding this feature, although that seems unlikely given that SONY intends to sell their own PS4 remote as was done for the PS3. The most likely outcome based on historical reference is that at some point down the line, a new version of Harmony remote software/firmware will add the necessary Bluetooth support to act as a remote for the PS4.

One solution in the case of PS4 has been the existence of SONY released solutions in the form of apps for tablets and smartphones which can then act as remotes for SONY devices (and other devices in many cases) and this may well translate to support for the PS4 as well.

Answer (score 3):

PS4 recognizes all brands of televisions through HDMI. If your TV supports it, you’ll need to go into the Settings on your PlayStation 4 and check the box next to “Activate HDMI Link”. Once you do that, your PS4 can be controlled by your normal TV remote and on most set-ups when you turn on the system it will also turn on your television and receiver to the correct inputs.

- Samsung: Anynet+
- Sharp: Aquos Link
- Sony: BRAVIA Link or Bravia Sync
- Hitachi: HDMI-CEC
- Pioneer: Kuro Link
- Toshiba: CE-Link, Regza Link
- LG: SimpLink
- Panasonic: HDAVI Control, EZ-Sync, VIERA Link
- Philips: EasyLink
- Mitsubishi: NetCommand for HDMI
- Vizio: No special name, however Vizio TVs that support HDMI-CEC only do so on HDMI input 1.
- On Onkyo receivers it’s called RIHD.

[Source](http://furiousfanboys.com/2013/11/how-to-know-if-your-tv-supports-hdmi-cec-controls-for-ps4-remote-controls)

Comment: And my receiver does HDMI-CEC too I think. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Logitech [have announced](http://blog.logitech.com/2013/11/22/xbox-one-coming-to-a-harmony-remote-near-you/) that they have been working with Microsoft to ensure that their range of Harmony remotes natively work with the Xbox One.

The "[My Harmony](http://myharmony.com)" website has been updated to provide support for the Xbox One, so you can set up your Harmony to control your Xbox One by visiting [myharmony.com](http://myharmony.com).